# How many AppID should I create for different projects

Tags: web-applications, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am a developer wanting to facebook integrated websites for clients. The Facebook for Websites [page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#personalization) says I need an appId for some of the integration features like facebook log in. But to create an AppId, it seems that a business facebook account cannot obtain the AppId.

What is the practice for creating AppId in this case? Do I use my personal facebook account to create the AppId and then use it for all projects? Or create a new AppId under my account for each project? Or create a dummy user account for each project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an app with your personal account, and add people as admins if you need the businesses to have control as well. In general, you should create 1 app per company/business you are building for. This makes sure people do not access customer data of other businesses on that account.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are suggesting 1 app per company I am building for, and all of them under my own facebook account? Is there an office reference on Facbook Developers on this issue you can point me to? Thank you for your help. ++

Comment: Correct, 1 app per company/business. And no, this is more of a "good practice and common sense" than official practice. Possible scenarios of combining apps: a) customers add app for Company A, but in turn give Company B access as well. b) customers that only wanted Company A to allow extended permissions (like posting) have now given it unknowingly to Company B. c) Removing the app for Company A would remove the app for Company B, even if they still wanted Company B to have it. d) If Company A abuses the platform (spam/rate-limits), Company B will get shut down as well.